# A fair die is rolled repeatedly. Let $X$ be the number of rolls needed to obtain a $5$ and $Y$ be the number of rolls needed to obtain as $6$.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

A fair die is rolled repeatedly. Let $X$ be the number of rolls needed to obtain a $5$ and $Y$ be the number of rolls needed to obtain as $6$.

Calculate $E(X|Y=2)$.

**My attempt**

As $X$ is the first time a 5 is rolled among independent trials, $X$ follows a geometric distribution with $p=\frac{1}{6}$.

$Y=2 \Rightarrow$ the first roll was not a $6$ and the second roll was a $6$.

This means a $5$ was obtained for the first time either on the first roll with $p=\frac{1}{5}$ or on at least the third roll with $p=1-\frac{1}{5}=\frac{4}{5}$.

$P(X=1|Y=2)=\frac{1}{5}, P(X=2|Y=2)=0, P(X=3|Y=2)=\frac{4}{5} \cdot 1 \cdot \frac{1}{6}, P(X=4|Y=2)=\frac{4}{5} \cdot 1 \cdot \frac{5}{6} \cdot \frac{1}{6}$

$E(X|Y=2)=(1/5)+(3)(4/5)(1/6)+4(4/5)(5/6)(1/6)+...= (1/5)+(4/5)\sum_{x=3}^{\infty}x \cdot (\frac{5}{6})^{x-3} \cdot (1/6)$

By letting $k=x-3$, I see that this sum equals $0.2(1)+0.8(8)=6.6$

One solution to this problem has the following: $E(X|X \ge 3)= \frac{1}{p}+2=6+2=8$. Thus $E(X|Y=2)=0.2(1)+0.8(8)=6.6$. But why is $E(X|X \ge 3)=8$?

Comment: Do you agree that $\mathbb E(X\mid X\geq1)=\mathbb EX=1/(1/6)=6$? More generally we have $\mathbb E(X\mid X\geq 1+k)=6+k$.

Comment: Yes because $E(X | X \ge 1)=E(X)=6$ since the geometric distribution has domain $\mathbb{Z^+}?$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\mathbb E(X\mid X\geq3)$ is the expectation of the number of rolls needed to obtain a $5$ under the condition that the rolls $1$ and $2$ do not provide a $5$.

We might say that the sequence of relevant rolls actually starts after $2$ rolls that are in vain, so that:$$\mathbb E(X\mid X\geq3)=\mathbb E(2+X)=2+\mathbb EX$$

Here $\mathbb EX=6$ since $X$ has geometric distribution (number of trials needed) with parameter $p=\frac16$.

This together explains that: $$\mathbb E(X\mid X\geq3)=2+6=8$$

Comment: Why do you exclude the possibility $X=1$?

Comment: @user Because we aim to find the expectation of $X$ *under the condition* that $X\geq3$ (that is $\mathbb E(X|X\geq3)$) and under that condition $X=1$ is not possible. By calculation of (unconditional) $\mathbb EX$ I do not exclude the possibility $X=1$.

Comment: I see. Obviously I did not read the question till the end.

Answer (score 0):

Recognize it as geometric mean

$E(X | Y = 2) = E(X) = \frac{1}{p} = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{6}} = 6$

Comment: Do you claim that the known result of obtaining 6 in the second trial does not change the expected value of $X$?